# Weird stepper issue when setting up Marlin printer

Tags: marlin, z-axis

When manually controlling the z-axis in reprap, it works fine. If I use the home button, it doesn't move. Instead, it stalls/freezes/hangs. It attempts to turn, but can't successfully make a full turn.

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3DP.SE! What is the status of the endstops? Could you send `M119` to the printer over USB using a terminal window like can be found in e.g. Pronterface software. Furthermore the question is very terse, please try to add more information and explain what you already tried to do to fix it. Please read [this](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/3d-printing-stack-exchange-question-checklist) to improve your question.

Comment: An alternate software to Pronterface would be Repetier Host. Troubleshooting questions need a maximum of information available to be viable - the more information you can provide, the more likely we'll find a solution with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lower the moving speed of the Z-axis motor, search for

> homing feed rate

in config.h as it looks like the given speed is to high.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like endstop signal for Z is inverted. In this case Z will move in manual mode but when homing it will try and stop as limit detected immediately. Change Z_MIN_ENDSTOP_INVERTING to opposite value.

Comment: Triggered stops cause marlin to only allow the axis to move away from the stop during homing. If it is not moving at all, this couldn't be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you run M503 you should be able to see your max speeds. They, along with your homing speeds, are probably far too high and causing skipped steps (no movement). You can lower them down temporarily with M203. http://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M203.html